# Error when I'm clicking and try to make inAppPurchase function?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I receive the follwing error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
>   android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle) on a null object reference

when I'm clicking my button:

```
skuDetails = billingService.getSkuDetails(3, "com.android.vending.billing", "inapp", querySkus);
```

All parameters have not null values, but in the same time i got such error.

And full code is below:

```
connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        billingService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            billingService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

        }
    };

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.BIND");
    intent.setPackage("com.android.vending.billing");
    getBaseContext().bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
            skuList.add(ITEM_SKU);
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

            Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + querySkus.getStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST"));



            Bundle skuDetails = null;
            try {
                skuDetails = billingService.getSkuDetails(3,
                        "com.android.vending.billing",
                        "inapp", querySkus);           

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = billingService
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            base64EncodedPublicKey);
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are new here - Welcome to Stack Overflow - The error means `billingService` is null. You have not got an instance of your service when you try to use it.

Take a look through [the tutorials](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) and also some info on [how to diagnose a NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)